# Understanding Sequencing in Functional Programming

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory

I'm mostly a practical guy but I find this interesting.

I have been thinking about monadic sequencing and there are a few
things that I need clarified. So at the risk of sounding silly here
it is:

The monadic member bind

`bind ::   m b -> (b -> m c) -> m c`

can sequence "actions" giving you explicit access to intermediate values.

How does this give me more than the categorical member `(.)`:

`(.) :: cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c`

With this I can sequence and get access to intermediate values.
After all `(f . g) x = f(g (x))`.

Why do I need `bind` for sequencing if I can sequence with `(.)`?

Comment: The monadic version of `(.)` is `(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)`, Kleisli composition.

Comment: This gives you *less* actually. `C(a, b) = a -> m b` forms a category with `bind` as composition and `return` as identity, the *Kleisli category* of `m`.

Comment: It is also not quite true that in `f (g x)` the `g x` must happen first. This would be true only under strict semantics. But, as it stands, it could be before, while or not at all.

Comment: Cool I think I'm starting to learn how to read the hints types give away a bit better. I need to read Benjamin C. Pierces book Basic CT for CS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're on the right track. Every monad gives rise to so-called [Kleisli category](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrow_tutorial#Kleisli_Arrows). For every monad `m` its corresponding Kleisli category has arrows `a -> m b` and they can be composed using [>=>](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-), which is defined as

```
f >=> g     = \x -> f x >>= g
```

[Kleisli](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v:Kleisli) type encapsulates this in Haskell type system, you can see that it has instance

```
instance Monad m => Category (Kleisli m) where
    id = Kleisli return
    (Kleisli f) . (Kleisli g) = Kleisli (g >=> f)
```

So sequencing computations within this category is just sequencing operations using `>=>`, which can be expressed equivalently using `>>=`.

We define monads using `return` and `>>=` because it's more convenient, but we could define them as well using `return` and `>=>` if we wanted.

(See also [my answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/161464/61231) to [Different ways to see a monad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/161443/61231).)

Comment: I was typing away but you beat me to it, so I'll just add that the Monad laws are equivalent to the laws that make `Kleisli m` a category: left and right absorption of identity, and associativity of composition. Note also that `ArrowApply` defines the extra structure which an `Arrow` must have to yield a monad. `Kleisli m` is not just a category but an `Arrow`, and of course possesses the extra `ArrowApply` structure, but not all `Arrow`s do.

Comment: @pigworker: The laws are not 100% equivalent in that you need to add an extra `(g >=> h) . f = (f.g) >=> h` law in order to deduce the `>>=` laws from the `>=>` ones. I don't remember what this is called but it caught me when doing some exercises.